# Laying out Responsive Grid for div with Sub Elements using CSS

Tags: html, css

Im trying to figure out the best approach to laying out the following design in html and CSS

[image]

The picture above shows the page, with a single 'Containing Div' which has a some fixed height (but the exact height is different depending on media queries).

The question I have is how to achieve this layout where;

1. The Containing Div set to the full width of a page, but height determined in css
2. The Centered Div centered both vertically and horizontally
3. The Sub Div aligned horizontally, but positioned only below the 'centered div' by some fixed amount
4. Not using any absolute positioning

I have notionally tried to use Flexbox to center the the 'centered div' which works great, however, the 'sub div' is not positioning itself correctly

```css
.containing-div {
  min-height: 750px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;  
}

.centered-div {

}

.sub-div {

}
```

```html
  <div class="containing-div">
    <div class="centered-div">
        <span>Centered Vertically and Horizontally</span>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-div"> 
        <span>Sub Div</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please add relevant code of what you have already tried

Comment: @SuperDJ i've added a code snippet, but not sure if the approach im using is a good one for what im trying to achieve

Comment: I do not see any bootstrap class here. native class can handle this layout (bootstrap 4 + flex class )

Comment: Yep ok fair point @G-Cyr , Ill scratch out the bootstrap requirements for the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while you are looking for the boostrap class, a pseudo might be usefull too.

basicly the idea is to share room left from centered element in between the subdiv and an unseen pseudo:

example:

```css
.containing-div {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* show middle & center */
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 50%), linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 50%)
}

.centered-div {}

.containing-div:before {
  content: ''
}

.containing-div:before,
.sub-div {
  flex: 1;
}
/* extra */
body {
margin:0;
}
div div,
 :before {
  padding: 1em
}
```

```html
<div class="containing-div">
  <div class="centered-div">
    <span>Centered Vertically and Horizontally</span>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-div">
    <span>Sub Div</span>
  </div>
</div>
```